# Uncaught ReferenceError: functionName is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have checked out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612218/how-can-i-call-a-javascript-function-when-checkbox-is-checked) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067887/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-in-document-readyfunction) but it didn't really help me.

I have a ASP:CheckBox control shown below.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chbArchived" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("archived") %>' OnClick=changeExpirationDate() />
```

My JavaScript are follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert("got here");
            $('.insDateTime').datetimepicker({
                ampm: true
            });
            changeExpirationDate(){
                var currentDate = new Date;
                var futureDateTime = (currentDate.getMonth() + 4) + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear() + ' ' + formatAMPM(currentDate);
                var expiredDateTime = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear() + ' ' + formatAMPM(currentDate);
                var archivedCheckbox = document.getElementById('cphContent_fmvNewsEventList_chbArchived').checked;
                if(archivedCheckbox == true)
                {
                    document.getElementById('cphContent_fmvNewsEventList_txtExpirationDate').value = expiredDateTime;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById('cphContent_fmvNewsEventList_txtExpirationDate').value = futureDateTime;
                }
            };
            function formatAMPM(date) {
                var hours = date.getHours();
                var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                hours = hours % 12;
                hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
                var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
                return strTime;
            };
        });        
    </script>
```

The problem is I kept getting this JavaScript error "Uncaught ReferenceError: changeExpirationDate is not defined" when I clicked on the checkbox. Any suggestion/help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
});
changeExpirationDate(){    <-- where is the function declaration?
    var currentDate = new Date;
```

aka

```
function changeExpirationDate () {
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a very stupid mistake -- totally forgot about.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
changeExpirationDate(){
```

to

```
function changeExpirationDate(){
```

The first makes it look like you are trying to call it; the second defines it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after looking at one more time, I found out it was a very stupid mistake. I forgot the "function" before the function name, changeExpirationDate(), thus, it was giving me this error.

Comment: Sure, but it'll still fail if you declare it inside the `.ready()` callback like that. A handler assigned as an HTML attribute executes in the global scope.